# C++ DirectInput Mouse Scroll Wheel with a Laptop Touchpad

Tags: c++, directx, directinput

When using DirectInput, it is my understanding that the mouse wheel delta should be stored in DIMOUSESTATE objects lZ variable.  However, when I am scrolling with my laptop touchpad instead of an actual mouse with a wheel, it seems like the scroll is not being recognized since 1Z remains zero always.  Is there a better solution than using [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645617%28VS.85%29.aspx) if that will even work?  Since I am currently using DirectInput for the rest of the input I would like to stay consistent and use that but how can I get the scroll information from the touchpad?

Thanks!