# No mousewheel events when using touchpad

Tags: windows, mousewheel, touchpad

I'm having troubles retrieving mousewheel events when my program is running on my laptop and when I'm scrolling using the touchpad.

I was initially using DirectInput to catch input events, but I've read here and there that DirectInput wasn't able to handle scroll events sent by touchpads.

I did some extra researchs and fell on this old topic: [C++ DirectInput Mouse Scroll Wheel with a Laptop Touchpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186792/c-directinput-mouse-scroll-wheel-with-a-laptop-touchpad)

So i've tried to use a PeekEvent loop to catch my mouse inputs. Everything wen fine when using a real mouse, but when I switched to my laptop, ta-da: no WM_MOUSEWHEEL events received. (And this guy predicted it )
I don't receive any WM_VSCROLL or WM_GESTURE event either.

Additionnaly I've made another program based on wxWidgets and in this case, the mouse wheel events are propery catched by the application. I've parsed the source code to see how wxWidgets retrieve windows events and, except if I'm missing something, it seems to be the exact same code as mine.

Is there some kind of voodoo magic trick to catch mouse wheel events generated by a touchpad? 
I can provide more informations about my code if needed.

Thanks

EDIT:

I did some extra debug to find what's going on:

First, I was wrong saying I don't catch WM_MOUSEWHEEL event at all. In fact, in the WindowProc Callback I actually receive wheel events.

However, the PeekMessage call doesn't return any event.

I could eventually change the way I collect mouse events to do it directly in the WindowProc callback, but I'll need to do some weird stuff just to handle something that should be working the same way using both a real mouse or a touchpad.

Comment: This could be useful: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/995290/How-to-react-to-touchpad-scrolling-in-WPF

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unless I'm missing something I don't see any solution in this discussion.

Comment: BTW, assuming it's Synaptics touchpad, [here](https://superuser.com/a/377217/135260)'s a trick that fixes the way how touchpad driver sends the mouse wheel events.